# What is the range of T(V) ?

Tags: linear-transformations

T: V->V

V=all diffrentiable functions

and T(f)=g=x times derivative of f(x)

So, this is a linear transformation,

I found out that nullity is 1 because all constant functions are null space

And I think rank is infinite because V is infinite

and I think range of T(V) is all diffrentiable functions with no constant term

is that right?

Comment: assuming by all constant functions you mean all $C^1$ functions, then the range would be all continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

The range of $T$ is the set of continuous functions $g$ where $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g(x)}x$ exists. In particular, every $g$ in range($T$) must have $g(0)=0$. What you said about the range being all functions with no constant term would be correct if $V$ were the space of analytic functions, those representable by a power series. But since $V$ in your cases is general differentiable functions, range$(V)$ will contain more than these. For example, 
$$
g(x)=x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)
$$
is hit by $f(x)=\int_0^x t\cos(1/t)\,dt$, but $g$ is not analytic, since it is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Is it ok for me to say all diffrentiable functions with no constant? Then by saying that, I could eliminate the possibility of having function that you just explained